# Upload files from website

Tags: html, vba, asp-classic, upload

All I want to do is allow the user to browse through their folders to look for a file, select it and then press submit which saves the file to my server as well as the path to the saved file.

How would someone do this? (Some sort of tutorial website would help a lot)

Comment: You can use a component if you can add one to the server. If not, there are other options (albeit slower).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[4guysfromrolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20180312071127/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/webtech/LearnMore/Upload.asp) have a pretty good overview of the different methods, including tutorials and third-party components.  You should look into this link and see what fits your taste.

Comment: any time...i used to have to do a lot of ASP related file uploading, and it was a painful process - 4guysfromrolla is a really good resource for these sorts of things

Answer (score 1):

4guysfromrolla is OK, but their code isn't very well written a lot of the time.

I always use an object for the task, like Persists ASP Upload, check it out.  The documentation is good.

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to not use software that I have to pay for.